# Search full and partial text value using wildcard from elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, nosql

I have below simple table with title and code column from elasticsearch like below

```
{ title: 'test1', code: 'ZjS3d3k8z',... },
{ title: 'test2 with more words', code: 'AjS3d2k1z',... }
```

I am trying to filter title and code by using wildcard as shown below,

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "creation_date": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    "_score"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "account_id": 100
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "code": "?test2 with"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "title": "*test2 with*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_number_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

The above query works with expected results /fails with no results on below case

```
> 'test1' <---- works(return expected result) when i try to search single word
> 'test2' <---- works(return expected result) when i try to search single word
> 'test2 with'<---- fails(return empty result) when i try to search more than one word with space'
> 'test2 with more words' <---- fails(return empty result) when i try to search full title
```

When i try search code like below, It always return empty result!!!

```
"should": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "code": "?ZjS3d3k8z"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "title": "*ZjS3d3k8z*"
          }
        }
      ]
```

I want to search title/code with partial/full value from millions of records using elasticsearch. Kindly advise.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say fail and works? Is that the query doesn't give you the expected result or it results in some error. Please add all the different kinds of input and expected output combinations.

Comment: Opster, Now updated question. The above query works on some case with expected results and on some case with no results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For wildcard perform search on "keyword" field instead of "text" . For text data type, string is analyzed, broken into tokens while keyword field are stored as it is.
"test2 with more words" is stored as ["test2","with","more","words"] and your wild card input is being matched against these tokens hence no doc is returned.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "code.keyword": "*test2 with*"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "title.keyword": "*test2 with*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Mappings created with dynamic template have keyword sub field for  each text type. If you have created the mapping explicitly then you need to add the keyword subfield

```
"title": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
```

Wild cards have poor performance, there are better alternatives.

1. Match/Match_phrase/Match_phrase_prefix

if you are searching for whole tokens like "test2 with". You can simply a match query, all documents with contain tokens "test2" and "with" will be returned

```
"should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "code": {
              "query": "test2 with",
              "operator": "and"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "title": {
              "query": "test2 with",
              "operator": "and"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
```

If order of tokens matter, you can use match_phrase.

If you want to search for partial tokens, use match_phrase_prefix.
Prefix match is only done on last token in search input ex. "test2 w"

2. [Edge N grams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html)

> The edge_ngram tokenizer first breaks text down into words whenever it
>   encounters one of a list of specified characters, then it emits
>   N-grams of each word where the start of the N-gram is anchored to the
>   beginning of the word.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Tokens generated:

```
"tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "te",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 2,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "tes",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 3,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "test",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "test2",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 3
    },
    {
      "token" : "wi",
      "start_offset" : 6,
      "end_offset" : 8,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 4
    },
    {
      "token" : "wit",
      "start_offset" : 6,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 5
    },
    {
      "token" : "with",
      "start_offset" : 6,
      "end_offset" : 10,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 6
    }
  ]
```

this will let you perform search like "tes wit" i.e any token can be partial unlike match_phrase_prefix which only does prefix search on last token

3. [N Grams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html)

> The ngram tokenizer first breaks text down into words whenever it
>   encounters one of a list of specified characters, then it emits
>   N-grams of each word of the specified length.
>
> N-grams are like a sliding window that moves across the word - a
>   continuous sequence of characters of the specified length

You can search for partial token even in middle  "est" will match test

4. [Suggesters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html)
   They provide search as you type functionality

You can choose any among these based on your requirement